# How can I us a single var for multiple values?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get random values, getting random array elements.
The problem that when i generate them, they are the same. 
This may be a stupid question, but how can I get a random value for each instance.
 
my HTML looks like this

```
Our Array consists of:<br>
<span id="massParts"></span><br><br>
Generating a word from syllables:<br>
<span id="oneWord"></span><br><br>
Generating a sentence from several words<br>
<span id="oneSentence"></span>
```

What I am trying to achieve is getting a sentence of randomly generated words. I seethe only solution to create multiple words and then putting them together. But this is not the solution for a bigger text.

my script is:

```
<script>
    // creating an array of syllables
var parts = ["ing", "er", "a", "on", "po", "i", "re", "tion"];
var partsAsString = parts.join(', ');

    // display syllables array elements
document.getElementById("massParts").innerHTML = partsAsString;

    // getting random element from an array
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);
var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);

    // making a word with one, two and three syllables
var oneSylWord = parts[a];
var twoSylWord = parts[a]+parts[b];
var threeSylWord = parts[a]+parts[b]+parts[c];

    //putting three words into an array
var newWord = [oneSylWord, twoSylWord, threeSylWord];

    // taking one of those free words fron the new array
var randWord = newWord[Math.floor(Math.random() * newWord.length)];

    // display a random 1,2,3 syllable word
document.getElementById("oneWord").innerHTML = randWord;

   // generating a sentence
var sentence = randWord + " " +  randWord +  " " +  randWord + ".";
document.getElementById("oneSentence").innerHTML = sentence;
</script>
```

I understand that I display the same var randWord and that causes the repetition. but how can I avoid using multiple variables for it.

Thank you.

here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2j9jpcoo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code into a [**function**](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html) and call it multiple times to get a (potentially) different value every time it is called:

```
function getRandomValue(arr);
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}


var sentence = getRandomValue(newWord) + " " +  getRandomValue(newWord) +  " " +  getRandomValue(newWord) + ".";
```

Functions allow you to organize and reuse code. From the above link:

> Functions are the bread and butter of JavaScript programming. The concept of wrapping a piece of program in a value has many uses. It is a tool to structure larger programs, to reduce repetition, to associate names with subprograms, and to isolate these subprograms from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the following algorithm in generating random numbers, according to [this article](http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/) where it mentions it is even better in performance but to be honest I did not benchmark it but you could check this in [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkFN/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ZCkFN), just run it and see the benchmark results

```
// the initial seed
Math.seed = 6;

// in order to work 'Math.seed' must NOT be undefined,
// so in any case, you HAVE to provide a Math.seed
Math.seededRandom = function(max, min) {
    max = max || 1;
    min = min || 0;

    Math.seed = (Math.seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
    var rnd = Math.seed / 233280;

    return min + rnd * (max - min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-organized your code a bit and created some re-usable functions to get a different random word each time. In this case we can skip the variable and use the return value from the function directly:

```
// creating an array of syllables
var a, b, c, newWord;
var parts = ["ing", "er", "a", "on", "po", "i", "re", "tion", "con", "de", "sta"];
var partsAsString = parts.join(', ');

// display syllables array elements
document.getElementById("massParts").innerHTML = partsAsString;

function shuffleLetters() {
  // getting random element from an array
  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);
  c = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);

  var oneSylWord = parts[a];
  var twoSylWord = parts[a]+parts[b];
  var threeSylWord = parts[a]+parts[b]+parts[c];

  //putting three words into an array
  newWord = [oneSylWord, twoSylWord, threeSylWord];
}

function getRandomWord() {
  shuffleLetters();

  // taking one of those free words fron the new array
  return newWord[Math.floor(Math.random() * newWord.length)];
}

// making a word with one, two and three syllables
shuffleLetters();

// display a random 1,2,3 syllable word
document.getElementById("oneWord").innerHTML = getRandomWord();

// generating a sentence
var sentence = getRandomWord() + " " +  getRandomWord() +  " " +  getRandomWord() + ".";

document.getElementById("oneSentence").innerHTML = sentence;
```